# RecyclerView adds Fragment to the wrong position in the list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that has many `ViewHolder` types. One of those `ViewHolder` (`GoalCardViewHolder`) holds a `View` that is just a container for displaying a `Fragment`. In my chat app this `ViewHolder` is used by two different `ViewTypes`, this is for `UserInput` and `ChatItem` view types.

The `UserInput` type represents when the user needs to act.
[User Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXhXp.png)

The `ChatItemType` represent any of the other elements in the Chat, when the user inputs a new goal, a `ChatItemType.GoalCard` is created: [ChatItem.GoalCard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyCCK.png)

Note that both types use the same `ViewHolder`.

**The problem**

[When the user is trying to create a new Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhPQu.png) , I expect a new `UserInput` to be created at the bottom of the chat. [However, the previous `GoalCardViewHolder` is being re-used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvaX8.png)(this happens a few times, until the list grows long enough that the ViewHolder gets recycled, when that happens the new view is added at the bottom as expected).

**The source code**
Apologies for the lengthy pasting but the Adapter and MainChatFragment are very complex (please do let me know if you need anything else):

*MainChatFragment.kt*

```
class MainChatFragment(
    private val viewModel: MainChatViewModel,
    private val chatAdapter: ChatAdapter,
    private val chatToolbar: ChatToolbar,
    private val chatDaySelector: ChatDaySelector,
    private val dayOfStudyProvider: DayOfStudyProvider,
    private val subjectMenuFragment: SubjectMenuFragment,
    private val chatSpeedHelper: ChatSpeedHelper,
) : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var dayOfStudySelectorView: DayOfStudySelectorView
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentChatBinding
    private var scrollDistance: Int = 0
    private val cancelOnPauseScope = CancelOnPauseCoroutineScope(this)
    private val bufferedChatItems = mutableListOf<IChatItem>()

    private val arguments: MainChatFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentChatBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        dayOfStudySelectorView = binding.dashboardView
        dayOfStudySelectorView.init(dayOfStudyProvider, chatDaySelector)
        setupChatItemList()
        subjectMenuFragment.closeMenuCallback = { shouldDiscardItems ->
            if (!shouldDiscardItems) {
                bufferedChatItems.forEach {
                    addChatItem(it)
                }
            }
            bufferedChatItems.clear()
        }

        chatAdapter.removeLastUserInput = this::removeLastUserInput
        chatAdapter.subjectMenuButtonOnClick = this::openSubjectMenuFragment

        chatToolbar.setMenuButtonOnClickListener {
            openSubjectMenuFragment()
        }
    }

    private fun removeLastUserInput() {
        viewModel.removeLastUserInputAndLogMessage()
    }

    private fun openSubjectMenuFragment() {
        if (!subjectMenuFragment.isAdded) {
            subjectMenuFragment.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "subjectMenu")
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        observeChatItemActions() // Should be last entry in here
    }

    @Suppress("IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_ANY")
    private fun observeChatItemActions() {
        cancelOnPauseScope.launch {
            viewModel.chatItemActionFlow()
                .onStart { viewModel.onUserEnteredChat(arguments.hasJustActivated) }
                .transform {
                    if (it is ChatItemAction.AddChatItemAction) {
                        val delayMs = chatSpeedHelper.itemDelay(it.chatItem)
                        if (delayMs > 0) {
                            delay(delayMs)
                        }
                        if (subjectMenuFragment.isVisible) {
                            bufferedChatItems.add(it.chatItem)
                            return@transform
                        }
                    }
                    emit(it)
                }
                .collect {
                    if (!isVisible) {
                        return@collect
                    }
                    when (it) {
                        is ChatItemAction.AddChatItemAction -> {
                            addChatItem(it.chatItem)
                        }
                        is ChatItemAction.SetChatItemsAction -> {
                            chatAdapter.showWaitingBubble = false
                            binding.emptyChatText.isVisible =
                                it.chatItems.isEmpty() && !it.chatEnabled
                            chatAdapter.items = it.chatItems.map { item -> ChatViewItem(item) }
                        }
                        is ChatItemAction.RemoveAllItemsAction -> {
                            chatAdapter.removeAllItems()
                        }
                        is ChatItemAction.RemoveLastItemAction -> {
                            chatAdapter.conditionallyRemoveLastChatItem(it.predicate)
                        }
                    }.let { } // Make when exhaustive
                }
        }
    }

    private fun addChatItem(chatItem: IChatItem) {
        if (chatItem is ChatItem) {
            chatItem.chatBackgroundAction?.let { chatBackgroundAction ->
                viewModel.launchChatBackgroundAction(chatBackgroundAction)
            }
        }
        val chatViewItem = ChatViewItem(chatItem)
        chatAdapter.showWaitingBubble = chatViewItem.shouldShowPendingBubble()
        chatAdapter.addChatItem(chatViewItem)
        binding.emptyChatText.isVisible = false
    }

    private fun setupChatItemList() {
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireView().context)
        linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
        with(binding.chatList) {
            layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
            adapter = chatAdapter
            addItemDecoration(
                DividerItemDecoration(
                    requireView().context,
                    linearLayoutManager.orientation
                ).apply {
                    setDrawable(
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                            requireView().context,
                            R.drawable.divider_chat
                        )!!
                    )
                })

            addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    scrollDistance += dy
                    if (dy < 0 &&
                        (scrollDistance.absoluteValue >= measuredHeight || !binding.chatList.canScrollVertically(
                            -1
                        ))
                    ) {
                        dayOfStudySelectorView.revealDaySelector()
                    } else if (dy > 0) {
                        dayOfStudySelectorView.hideDaySelector()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

*ChatAdapter.kt*

```
class ChatAdapter(
    private val widgetHandler: WidgetHandler,
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseChatItemViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater

    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private val lastDivider = ChatViewItem(ChatItemType.LastDivider)
    private val pendingMessage = ChatViewItem(ChatItemType.PendingMessage)
    private val staticPendingView = false

    var showWaitingBubble: Boolean = true
        set(value) {
            if (value != showWaitingBubble) {
                setShowingWaitingBubble(value)
            }
            field = value
        }

    var removeLastUserInput: () -> Unit = {}
    var subjectMenuButtonOnClick: () -> Unit = {}
    lateinit var onGoalSettingStarted: (GoalCardProgressListener) -> Unit

    private fun setShowingWaitingBubble(value: Boolean): Int {
        var updatedIndex = -1
        if (_items.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (!value) {
                _items.lastIndexOf(pendingMessage)
                    .takeIf { it >= 0 }
                    ?.let {
                        _items.removeAt(it)
                        updatedIndex = it
                    }
            } else {
                if (!hasPendingBubble() && shouldShowPendingBubble(getLastRealChatItem().second)) {
                    val divider = hasLastDivider()
                    updatedIndex = Math.max(0, _items.size - divider.toBitInteger())
                    _items.add(updatedIndex, pendingMessage)
                }
            }
        }
        if (updatedIndex != -1) {
            scrollToBottom()
        }
        return updatedIndex
    }

    private var _items = ArrayList<ChatViewItem>()
    var items: List<ChatViewItem>
        get() = _items
        set(value) {
            _items.clear()
            _items.addAll(value)
            if (value.isNotEmpty()) {
                setShowingWaitingBubble(showWaitingBubble)
            }
            _items.add(lastDivider)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
            scrollToBottom()
        }

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView
        context = recyclerView.context
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(recyclerView.context)
        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val chatViewItem = items[position]
        return when (chatViewItem.type) {
            ChatItemType.UserInput, ChatItemType.DisabledUserInput -> {
                val inputType = chatViewItem.inputType ?: npe("chatViewItem.inputType")
                when (inputType) {
                    is InputType.GoalSettingCard -> R.layout.goal_card
                    else -> -1 // deleted other viewTypes for stackOverflow
                }
            }
            ChatItemType.GoalCard -> R.layout.goal_card
            else -> -1 // deleted other viewTypes for stackOverflow
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseChatItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val chatViewItem = items[position]
        when (chatViewItem.type) {
            ChatItemType.UserInput, ChatItemType.DisabledUserInput -> {
                val inputType = chatViewItem.inputType ?: npe("chatViewItem.inputType")
                when (inputType) {
                    is InputType.GoalSettingCard -> {
                        val goalCardFragment = GoalCardFragment()
                        goalCardFragment.initialProgress =
                            GoalBuilder() // Fixme use goal builder from topic interactor
                        onGoalSettingStarted.invoke(goalCardFragment)
                        goalCardFragment.arguments =
                            bundleOf(GoalCardFragment.FLOW_TYPE_EXTRA to inputType.flowType)
                        goalCardFragment.onCanceledCallback =
                            (holder as GoalCardViewHolder).canceledListener
                        goalCardFragment.onCompletedCallback = holder.completedListener

                        if (inputType.flowType == FlowType.COMPLETE_GOAL) {
                            context.activity().supportFragmentManager
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .replace(
                                    holder.binding.goalCardContainer.id,
                                    goalCardFragment,
                                    GOAL_CARD_FRAGMENT_AS_USER_INPUT
                                )
                                .commit()
                        } else {
                            TODO("Need implementation")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ChatItemType.GoalCard -> {
                gson.fromJson(chatViewItem.text, GoalCardParameters::class.java)
                GoalCardFragment().let {
                    if (chatViewItem.data is GoalSettingData) {
                        it.initialProgress = (chatViewItem.data as GoalSettingData).goalBuilder
                    }
                    context.activity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(
                            (holder as GoalCardViewHolder).binding.goalCardContainer.id,
                            it as GoalCardFragment,
                            GOAL_CARD_FRAGMENT_AS_CHAT_ITEM
                        )
                        .commit()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        @LayoutRes viewType: Int
    ): BaseChatItemViewHolder {
        val itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(viewType, parent, false)
        return when (viewType) {
            R.layout.goal_card -> {
                GoalCardViewHolder(itemView).apply {
                    setOnCanceledListener {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            removeLastUserInput()
                            removeFragmentByTag(GOAL_CARD_FRAGMENT_AS_USER_INPUT)
                            widgetHandler.onWidgetDone(
                                userResponse = UserResponse(
                                    WIDGET_DISMISSED_WITH_VALUE + "cancelled"
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    setOnCompletedListener {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            val goalData = UserResponseData.GoalData(it)
                            removeLastUserInput()
                            removeFragmentByTag(GOAL_CARD_FRAGMENT_AS_USER_INPUT)
                            widgetHandler.onWidgetDone(
                                userResponse = UserResponse(
                                    WIDGET_DISMISSED_WITH_VALUE + "completed", data = goalData
                                )
                            )

                            // TODO api
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("View type not mapped to a view holder")
        }
    }

    private fun removeFragmentByTag(tag: String) {
        context.activity().supportFragmentManager.apply {
            findFragmentByTag(tag)?.let {
                beginTransaction()
                    .remove(it)
                    .commit()
            }
        }
    }

    fun addChatItem(chatItemView: ChatViewItem) {
        val shouldShowPendingBubble = shouldShowPendingBubble(chatItemView)
        setShowingWaitingBubble(shouldShowPendingBubble)
        val hasPendingBubble = hasPendingBubble()
        val insertIndex = Math.max(
            0,
            itemCount - hasLastDivider().toBitInteger() - hasPendingBubble.toBitInteger()
        )
        _items.add(insertIndex, chatItemView)
        // sending notifyItemRangeChanged instead of notifyItemInserted is for a feeling of
        // scrolling also the pendingBubble, otherwise it looks like it's static view and it's not part of scrolling content
        if (staticPendingView && shouldShowPendingBubble) {
            notifyItemInserted(insertIndex)
        } else {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(insertIndex, 1 + hasPendingBubble.toBitInteger())
        }

        when (chatItemView.inputType) {
            is InputType.FreeText,
            is InputType.FreeTextWithLimit ->
                // for some reason RecyclerView scrolls up little bit when EditText is shown
                // basically aligns to bottom of line, not bottom of EditText =>
                // let RV do this nonsense and scroll down little bit later
                // however we have to do it sooner, we try to show the keyboard then
                recyclerView?.postDelayed(UiConst.keyboardHandlingDelay / 2) {
                    scrollToBottom()
                }
            else -> scrollToBottom()
        }
    }

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: BaseChatItemViewHolder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
        holder.onAttached()
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: BaseChatItemViewHolder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
        holder.onDetached()
    }

    fun removeAllItems() {
        _items.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun notifyItemChanged(chatViewItem: ChatViewItem) {
        notifyItemChanged(items.indexOf(chatViewItem))
    }

    fun conditionallyRemoveLastChatItem(predicate: (ChatViewItem) -> Boolean) {
        val (index, item) = getLastRealChatItem()
        if (item != null && predicate(item)) {
            _items.removeAt(index)
            notifyItemRemoved(index)
        }
    }

    private fun hasLastDivider(): Boolean = _items.lastOrNull()?.type == ChatItemType.LastDivider
    private fun hasPendingBubble(): Boolean {
        return (items.lastOrNull(1)?.type == ChatItemType.PendingMessage) ||
                (items.lastOrNull(0)?.type == ChatItemType.PendingMessage)
    }

    private fun getLastRealChatItem(): Pair<Int, ChatViewItem?> {
        if (!items.isEmpty()) {
            (items.size - 1 downTo 0).forEach { i ->
                val item = items[i]
                when (item.type) {
                    ChatItemType.LastDivider,
                    ChatItemType.PendingMessage -> {
                        /*ignore*/
                    }
                    else -> return Pair(i, item)
                }
            }
        }
        return Pair(-1, null)
    }

    private val skipPendingBubbleFor = listOf(
        ChatItemType.UserInput,
        ChatItemType.LastBotMessage
    )

    private fun shouldShowPendingBubble(chatItemView: ChatViewItem?): Boolean {
        return showWaitingBubble && !skipPendingBubbleFor.contains(chatItemView?.type)
    }

    private fun scrollToBottom() {
        (recyclerView?.layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager)?.scrollToPosition(itemCount - 1)
    }

    companion object {
        const val GOAL_CARD_FRAGMENT_AS_USER_INPUT = "goal-card-fragment-user-input"
        const val GOAL_CARD_FRAGMENT_AS_CHAT_ITEM = "goal-card-fragment-chat-item"
    }
}

abstract class BaseChatItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    open fun onAttached() {}

    open fun onDetached() {}

    open fun bind(chatViewItem: ChatViewItem) {}

    abstract val binding: ViewBinding?
}

abstract class BaseTextChatItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseChatItemViewHolder(itemView) {
    abstract val chatText: TextView
}

class GoalCardViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseChatItemViewHolder(itemView) {
    lateinit var canceledListener: (() -> Unit)
    lateinit var completedListener: ((GoalBuilder) -> Unit)

    fun setOnCanceledListener(canceledListener: () -> Unit) {
        this.canceledListener = canceledListener
    }

    fun setOnCompletedListener(completedListener: (GoalBuilder) -> Unit) {
        this.completedListener = completedListener
    }

    override val binding: GoalCardBinding = GoalCardBinding.bind(itemView)
}
```

*goal_card.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/goal_card_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest you create a simpler version of your code in order to increase the chances of getting an answer to your issue. You've added a lot of code with a very specific context - It is hard to follow. On another note, it considered a bad practice to pass parameters to a Fragment using the Fragment's constructor. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Comment: try setting ```recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20)``` to 0 instead of 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue and lesson learned was 'never use a Fragment in a `RecyclerView.ViewHolders`

I converted my fragment to a custom view and the problem is no longer happening.

I think it must have been an issue with the Fragment's lifecycle.